# Is it possible to set lineChart's xAxis values manually one-by-one using ios-charts in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I am creating a lineChart using ios-charts API in Swift language. On the xAxis there are dates in mm.dd-day format, for example 03.02-Wednesday. On the yAxis there are double values.I want to show on xAxis every monday and nothing else. The best solution what I found so far is 
`lineChart.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(6)`

This skip 6 label but it is working just if the chart datas start with a date which is Monday. 
Like here: [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r321.png)

But if my chart values start with Tuesday, I will see just Tuesday labels.: [what is not good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxiMp.png)

I had many ideas what should I do, but I couldn't find solution for it.
I am wondering if there is a function, what can set every label on xAxis one-by-one, so i can iter with a for loop on xAxis.values and set label visible if it's Monday and skip if it's not Monday. Something like this:

```
pseudo:
for i in lineChart.xAxis.values{
  if isMonday(){
    //set label visible
  }else{
    //set label invisible
}}
```

But I will really thanksful for every other solution for my problem. I have already tried to use this, but it didn't change label:

```
lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter?.stringForXValue(i, original: "Monday", viewPortHandler: cell.lineChartView.viewPortHandler)
```

I've tried to use setValueForKey, but I don't have keys, just indexes, and I thinking about to start setLabelsToSkip from an exact x value, but this function used for the whole chart.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your chart starts from Tuesday, and it shows Tuesday, which is by design, because it's first value. If you want always to display Monday, first, call
`lineChart.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(1)`, this affects xAxis.axisLabelModulus, which we must assure we can check every x value to see if it's monday.

then, you can override x axis rendrer's `drawLabels()` like:

```
public override func drawLabels(context context: CGContext, pos: CGFloat, anchor: CGPoint)
{
    ... // same as super
    for i in self.minX.stride(to: min(self.maxX + 1, xAxis.values.count), by: xAxis.axisLabelModulus)
    {
       let label = xAxis.values[i]
       if (!isMonday(label)) // implement isMonday() yourself
       {
           continue
       }
    ... // same as super
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your great answer, it is working. Anyway I would like to correct you, because if I setLabelsToSkip to 1, than i will see every second monday, so to see every monday I had to setLabelsToSkip(0)

Comment: it's up to you for the logic:)